# SFTP key error in Python when run in docker container

Tags: python, docker, sftp, pysftp

I made a python code that connects with a SFTP server and reads data. The python script worked well when I ran it on my machine.

For deployment purpose I needed a docker image. So I made one.

However when I run the docker container I get the following Error:

[image]

Dockerfile code:

```
FROM python:3
ADD sftp.py /
ADD config.properties /

RUN pip install pandas pysftp requests configparser

CMD ["python","./sftp.py"]
```

Python code for connecting to sftp:

```
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts(knownhosts=None)
cnopts.hostkeys = None
with pysftp.Connection(host=hostname,username=username,password=password,cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    sftp.chdir("Optimove_Output")
```

I am unable to figure out why it is not working within a docker container. As this code works when run without a container.

Comment: if you already know your host then add this in your Dockerfile `mkdir -p /root/.ssh/ && \ touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts && \
ssh-keyscan yourhost.com > ~/.ssh/known_hosts` so you will not need to mount the host directory.

Comment: The host can vary...need not be the same everytime.

Comment: you got solution to your problem??

Answer (score 2):

that is because in your localhost you have the file ´known_hosts´, try to run your  Container so:

```
docker run -v $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts:/root/.ssh/known_hosts sbtech2
```

Comment: How to make it flexible to automatically add every host as a known_hosts irrespective of the machine. Like I want the code to be machine independent

Comment: Like I meant if some other SFTP is to be connected. How to add that host to known host?

Comment: I tried that. Didn't worked

Comment: that will work, you need to have `known_hosts` just to make the warning go away.